# Spring Batch query with no '?' placeholders results in `Using SQL statement with '?' placeholders requires an ItemPreparedStatementSetter

Tags: spring-batch

```
    private String thisQuery = "SELECT count (*) FROM MYTABLE a WHERE a.TYPE_CD='THIS' AND a.CTGY_CD='2' WITH UR";


ItemWriter<ThisTable> ThisTableItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<ThisTable>()
BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql(thisQuery)
                .assertUpdates(true)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }
```

I cant figure out why it's asking me for a perparedStatementSetter if the query I am passing has no placeholders? :(

Im just using a simple select query to test the connection to the DB

Answer (score 1):

The writer is not supposed to issue a query of type `SELECT`. According to the code here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/f15edd414ada2c30ca136c243dbe0bb2fee447f3/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.java#L142-L156, you should either pass a `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` or use a `perparedStatementSetter`. The wording of the error is probably not precise with that regards. If you think this can be improved, you can open an issue with a minimal complete example.

Comment: Yep, I guess this should change the message. If you want execute a fixed param DELETE or UPDATE you must provide this fixed params to the writer, can't use the SQL sentence directly